Outer Automorphisms Which Affect Stabilizer Subgroups
I am looking for examples of homogeneous spaces, $\Sigma$, whose outer automorphisms, $\text{Out}(\Sigma)\subset \text{Auto}(\Sigma)$, act non-trivially on their stabilizer subgroups, $\text{Auto}(\Sigma,p)$. I would also be interested in proofs that this is not possible for certain kinds of spaces.
These spaces $\Sigma$ could be, for instance: a finite set, an affine vector space, a topological space, a smooth manifold, etc. Essentially any kind of structure would be of interest so long as $\text{Auto}(\Sigma)$ acts transitively on $\Sigma$.
Note that given this transitivity, all of $\text{Auto}(\Sigma)$'s stabilizer subgroup are conjugate to each other. Concretely, $\text{Auto}(\Sigma,p)$ is related to $\text{Auto}(\Sigma,q)$ via conjugation by the map $\varphi\in\text{Auto}(\Sigma)$ which maps $p$ to $q$ as $\varphi(p)=q$. Hence, these stabilizer subgroups are preserved (collectively) by any inner automorphism. Thus, if an automorphism acts non-trivially on these stabilizer subgroups then it must be an outer automorphism.
Here is a positive example of what I am looking for. Consider $S_6$ as the automorphism group for six points. It then has six $S_5$ stabilizer subgroups. These can be mapped via an outer automorphism to a different set of six $S_5$ subgroups. For details, see here.
[edit: I think the Fano plane is probably another example.]
A second positive example is suggested by this post related to the Klein 4
-group's action on a two element set $\{x,y\}$. But I would need to translate this example into some structured space, $\Sigma$, having the Klein 4-group as its automorphisms with this group action.
Here is a negative example. If $\text{Auto}(\Sigma)$ is Abelian (e.g., $\Sigma=(\mathbb{Z},+)$) then all of its stabilizer subgroups are trivial, $\text{Auto}(\Sigma,p)=\{1\}$. Hence, even if $\text{Auto}(\Sigma)$ were to include some outer automorphisms, they would act trivially on the space's stabilizer subgroups.
What I know so far:
$\bullet$ $S_{N=6}$ is the only symmetric group with this property
$\bullet$ From here: Let $N$ and $M$ be closed manifolds and let the identity components of their homeomorphism groups be isomorphic as groups $\text{Homeo}_0(M)\cong\text{Homeo}_0(N)$. Then $N$ and $M$ are isomorphic, and moreover, the homeomorphism between them induces the isomorphism, $\text{Homeo}_0(M)\cong\text{Homeo}_0(N)$, via conjugation. Taking $M=N$ we come close to showing that $\text{Homeo}_0(M)$ is entirely inner. Every automorphism of $\text{Homeo}_0(M)$ is achievable via conjugation by some element of $\text{Homeo}(M)$.
